# why are asserts enabled although -ea flag is not in my java command line

Tags: java

i don't have `-ea` flag on my `java` app command line however in remote debug / profiling with `visualvm` I do see that the `debugger` / `profiler` is passing thorugh this line, why is that? i didn't place any `-ea` on my java command line arguments.

Comment: Do the asserts create errors or are they just "ignored"?

Comment: @Smutje I placed a breakpoint inside the method the assert is supposert to call like `assert foo()` so i placed a breakpoint (remote debug to server) inside `foo()` and I see I reach that method from the assert stack.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? With JDK 8u11, I see from the byte code that `assert` checks a static field `$assertionsDisabled` **before** invoking anything passed to the `assert` statement (and skips the whole statement is this field is `true`), so when assertions are disabled what you describe should indeed not happen - probably visualvm enables assertions automatically?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Smutje i reverified that and it appears like indeed it does not enter the actual assert block, might have missed something.